# Mapping NDVI from single observation points using Landsat 8

Tags: csv, google-earth-engine

I am trying to grab an NDVI value for every observation in a .csv file, of which they have an eventDate, decimalLongitude and decimalLatitude). I can't get it to work at all. I've tried different Landsat ImageCollections and even MODIS ImageCollections. My .csv table is imported as "table". I feel like I'm missing something very simple that would solve my problem.

```
var csvTable = ee.FeatureCollection(table);

var addNDVI = function(feature) {

  var latitude = ee.Number(feature.get('decimalLatitude'));
  var longitude = ee.Number(feature.get('decimalLongitude'));
  
  var location = ee.Geometry.Point([longitude, latitude]);
  var date = ee.Date(feature.get('eventDate'));

  var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(location)
    .filterDate(date.advance(-3, 'day'), date.advance(3, 'day'))
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER', true);

  var leastCloudy = ee.Image(landsatCollection.first());

  var nir = leastCloudy.select(['SR_B5']);
  var red = leastCloudy.select(['SR_B4']); 

  var ndviValue = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

  return feature.set('NDVI', ndviValue);

};

var ndviTable = csvTable.map(addNDVI);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndviTable,
  description: 'ndvi_data_landsat',
  folder: 'your_output_folder',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

The error that occurs is when I try to download the export table through Earth Engine's Task Manger. It seems to indicate that I'm not providing an Image for the .map function but I'm failing to understand how.

"Error: Error in map(ID=00000000000000000000): Image.select: Parameter 'input' is required. (Error code: 3)"